# React: no <span> around text nodes

Tags: reactjs

According to React [15.0 release notes](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html), React is no longer supposed to emit `<span>` tags around text nodes. I tried that using [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/luxunekido/1/edit?html,js,output) and script

```jsx
const Span = () => (<span>a</span>)
const text = 'text'
const Text = () => (<span>{text}</span>)
const Div = (<div>
  <Span/><Span/><Span/><Text/>
</div>)
ReactDOM.render(Div, document.querySelector('#target'))
```

is rendered as

```html
<div data-reactroot="">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>a</span>
    <span>a</span>
    <span>text</span>
</div>
```

So it doesn't work. I'd expect string `a` to be rendered without surrounding `<span>` tags. How is this feature supposed to work? Is it necessary to enable it in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is used when writing something like this:

```
<div>{'a'}{'b'}</div>
```

"a" and "b" was surrounded by  tags and the dom was kinda full with this tags when using this multiple times in different components.

With 0.14.8 this was rendered as:

```
<div data-reactid=".0">
    <span data-reactid=".0.0">a</span>
    <span data-reactid=".0.1">b</span>
</div>
```

With 15.0 this is rendered as:

```
<div data-reactroot>
   <!-- react-text: 2 -->a<!-- /react-text -->
   <!-- react-text: 3 -->b<!-- /react-text -->
</div>
```

This is explained in https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/5753 and can be tested with something like https://codesandbox.io/s/N1znXxXL.